# Access denied using net.exe

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

I have a MSBuild build/deployment script that, as part of it's routine, stops and starts a couple of Windows Services from the CI server on the deployment server.

One of the commands in the script is

```
net.exe use \\<ip adddress of deployment computer> /user:<ip address of deployment server>\<user> <password>
```

As you can see, the CI server calls net on the deployment server and tells it to use a user that exists on the deployment server.

The problem is that this results in all further calls to return access denied errors.

What is the solution to this?  Must I use a domain account?

Comment: incidentally, the username in quesiton is an administrator on the deployment server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the net use command and specify login credentials to the remote server:

```
net use \\TheServer\ShareName /user:DomainName\User password
```

or

```
net use \\TheServer\ShareName /user:TheServer\User password
```

in this case the user you specify is a user defined locally on TheServer

after you finish do a `net use /delete` to close the connection

```
net use \\TheServer\ShareName /delete
```

you don't have to use a domain user as long as you specify credentials that the remote server can accept

if you can't use a server name you should be able to use an IP instead. if it doesn't work, try mapping the server name to an IP in the hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
and use the name in the net use command.

Anoher thing you should check is that it is allowed to access the file shares with non-guest accounts. [look here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread6257.html) (you do this on the server you are trying to access)

Comment: Hi Asher - I've done just that.  I've specified the ip address of the remote machine in the the username section of the net use command but it didn't work = it gave a access denied error as I said.  I can try the hosts file thing.  Why am I getting access denied with a admin account?

Comment: what OS do you have on the remote machine? can you otherwise access its file shares?

Comment: The remote machine is Windows Web Server 2008 R2.  In windows explorer on the CI machine I can do \\<ip of remote machine>.  When I do this I get a username and password prompt.  I enter the same u/p as the one specified in the net use call and I get in although I don't get very much back - blank screen.

Comment: This still isn't working.  I am dloing the following:

1. net.exe use \\<ip address> /delete
2. net.exe use \\<ip address> /user:<ip address>\<account> <password>
3. sc.exe \\<ip address> stop AC3.Mcfc.Notifier.Production

It is at step 3 that this fails.

Comment: look at the security event log (using event viewer) in the deployment server. you should see errors there, post them here

Comment: Here are the messages: The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account: svmaccount
Source Workstation: JENKINS2
Error Code: 0x0

Comment: Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
 Security ID:  MCFE1\svmaccount
 Account Name:  svmaccount
 Account Domain:  MCFE1
 Logon ID:  0x177fbc

Privileges:  SeSecurityPrivilege
   SeBackupPrivilege
   SeRestorePrivilege
   SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
   SeDebugPrivilege
   SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
   SeLoadDriverPrivilege
   SeImpersonatePrivilege

Comment: Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
 Security ID:  MCFE1\svmaccount
 Account Name:  svmaccount
 Account Domain:  MCFE1
 Logon ID:  0x177fbc

Privileges:  SeSecurityPrivilege
   SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
   SeLoadDriverPrivilege
   SeBackupPrivilege
   SeRestorePrivilege
   SeDebugPrivilege
   SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
   SeImpersonatePrivilege

Comment: An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
 Security ID:  NULL SID
 Account Name:  -
 Account Domain:  -
 Logon ID:  0x0

Logon Type:   3

New Logon:
 Security ID:  MCFE1\svmaccount
 Account Name:  svmaccount
 Account Domain:  MCFE1
 Logon ID:  0x177fbc
 Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
 Process ID:  0x0
 Process Name:  -

Network Information:
 Workstation Name: JENKINS2
 Source Network Address: 84.45.46.42
 Source Port:  3938

Comment: Detailed Authentication Information:
 Logon Process:  NtLmSsp 
 Authentication Package: NTLM
 Transited Services: -
 Package Name (NTLM only): NTLM V1
 Key Length:  0

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

Comment: The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

Comment: The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
 - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
 - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
 - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
 - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.

Comment: you need to make sure that the account you are using to access the deployment server (MCFE1\svmaccount) has the appropriate permissions both on the share (look for share permissions) and on the file system (look at the security tab in the folder properties dialog)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5916/discussion-between-sachin-and-asher)